# Flask session var erased in decorator

Tags: python, session, flask

I have a login_require decorator that needs to set a session variable when email comes as QS.

**decorators.py**

```
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get('is_logged', False):
            email = request.args.get('email', False)

            if not email:
                session['my_var'] = 'Hello'

            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

**views.py**

```
@route('/')
@login_required
def home():
    print session.get('my_var')
```

I am able to login and set the session var `my_var` for the `login()` view, but when I reach `home()` that var is `None` so I guess the decorator function is erasing it, but I know for sure it was set before in the login() view that the decorator redirected to.

How can I work it?

Comment: what are you using for sessions?

Comment: @JeffTratner I just need the decorator to set a value to the session if the view has 'email' in the querystring. It's used for later logic.

Comment: I was mistaken, didn't realize session was built into flask.

Comment: Is there any part of your application that removes `my_var` from the session? Maybe a logout view?

Comment: @Miguel well yes, logout does a session.clear(), but I don't think it's being reached, in fact this happens when I try to login.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza Well, maybe not, but since you haven't posted the complete code example only you can debug this.